# Laplace's equation on hyperbolic disk whose semi circles have different boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, hyperbolic-geometry, boundary-value-problem

On a flat disk, I can solve the Laplace's $\nabla^2 u = 0$ equation with different boundary conditions on semi circles like shown here [image: disk with different boundary conditions].

The answer to this is:

[image].

Here $a$ is the disk radius, and sum is over positive odd integers.

This is an unsolved problem in ML Boas's book (pg 644), but **I'm interested in a more general case where the disk is hyperbolic and the boundary conditions on upper and lower semi circles are $u_1$ and $u_2$.**

If the disk was flat, it's easy to adjust the constants to get the answer
$$
u = \frac{u_1 + u_2}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} (u_1 - u_2) \sum_{odd\; n} \left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^n \frac{\sin n\theta}{n}
$$

Now I'm trying to see what should happen when disk is hyperbolic, and I'm getting confused. I know that in general for 2d spaces one can write the metric as
$$
ds^2 = f(z, \overline{z}) dz d\overline{z}
$$
and therefore Laplace's equation on hyperbolic disk will reduce to Laplace's equation on the flat disk (only in the $z, \overline{z}$ coordinates?) and therefore the above solution should hold, provided I identify what is my $r$ and $a$ correctly.

The correct mapping between coordinate systems I suppose then should be polar to hyperbolic polar for which
$$
ds^2  = d\rho^2 + \sinh^2\rho d\phi^2
$$

Then that would mean $r \to \rho$ and $\theta \to \phi$. So

$$
u = \frac{u_1 + u_2}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} (u_1 - u_2) \sum_{odd\; n} \left(\frac{\rho}{a}\right)^n \frac{\sin n\phi}{n}
$$

should be the answer?

Does this make sense, or am I making some stupid mistake? How would you solve this problem?